# QLPreviewController issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mobile

I am trying to display the documents, images, PDF from the URL using QLPreviewController in iPad. It is working with lower versions upto iOS5 but the same thing which is not working with iOS6 and QLPreviewController am using as subview and i am not using the navigation controller.

Is there any other libraries are available for showing the documents in iOS.

Can any one help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do not add the QLPreviewController's view as subview to another view instead present modally as push to navigation stack refer  [QLPreviewController Document reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html)  or use  [UIDocumentInteractionController](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=uidocumentinteractioncontroller%20programming%20guide&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2FFileManagement%2FConceptual%2FDocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS%2FIntroduction%2FIntroduction.html&ei=4iX1UO2tJIaIrAeLkoCwBA&usg=AFQjCNGEoCFO5nq-nQLNf8jrmZK5-r9piA&bvm=bv.41018144,d.bmk)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need PDF and Images then check out the `UIImage+PDF` category: https://github.com/mindbrix/UIImage-PDF

This lets you render PDF images within a UIImageView the same as a JPG or any other kind of image.  This won't help if you need to render office documents however.  In which case, follow @pradeepa's advice.